# Что использовать для разработки кросс-платформенного мобильного приложения, активно использующего сеть и БД?

Tags: java, android, ios, кроссплатформенность, мобильные-приложения

Я программирую под Android и сейчас делаю простенькое мобильное приложение, по функционалу напоминающее обычный мессенджер.
В этом приложении я использую клиент-серверную архитектуру. Сервер написан на Java с расчётом на то, что будет развёрнут на Google App Engine. Нативный клиент под Android делает HTTP запросы к серверу, а сервер посылает сообщение через Google Cloud Messaging адресату или адресатам или отвечает на запрос объектами в JSON-формате. Кэш в СУБД SQLite.

И вот сейчас *(когда приложеньице уже почти готово =))* я начал задумываться как же мне портировать (хотя бы часть функционала) на другие платформы: iOS и Windows Phone. Писать под каждую платформу своё приложение с нуля, мне кажется, будет затратным, т.к. я раньше не программировал под iOS и Windows Phone. Пожалуйста, если вы обладаете богатым опытом в области создания кросс-платформенных мобильных приложений, **подскажите, как можно упростить создание и поддержку таких приложений**.

Вот, что я нашёл:
[image: продукты для создания кросс-платформенных приложений]

```
Delphi XE          | Delphi, native compilation  | Delphi developers
Unity3D            | C#, UnityScript, Boo        | Game developers
```

Сейчас я смотрю в сторону [j2objc](http://j2objc.org), [JUniversal](http://juniversal.org) и [Appery.io](https://appery.io) (грубо говоря, обёртка над [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com)). И у меня такой вопрос: **Какой из этих продуктов наиболее подходит для моего приложения?**

В частности,

- Смогу ли я использовать вместе с ними [RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit) и [ActiveAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com)?
- Будут ли работать Push Notifications (GCM / APN / MPNS)?

**ps**. Я рассматривал и отказался от [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/ru) и [Delphi XE](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi), потому что, мне кажется, они сильно увеличат размер моего небольшого приложения. Я отказался от [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com), потому что я не .Net-разработчик.

Comment: Я не специалист в мобильной разработке, и уж в кроссплатформенных продуктах под мобильные. Но, как мне кажется, вы сначала будете в восторге от того, что "вау, я написал один раз и оно работает везде", а потом вылезут какие-нибудь подводные камни, косяки, которые придется обходить большими усилиями.
В общем, сделать сразу хорошо всем, вряд ли получится.
P.S. Еще раз упомяну, что это моё частное мнение, не претендующее на объективность.

Comment: Когда создавал свое небольшое приложение - использовал PhoneGap / jQuery Mobile и удаленную базу данных Mongo от MongoLABS. Само приложение представляло просто список данных, получаемых с базы, разбитый по датам. Написание с этим стеком представляет собой реализацию небольшого веб-сайта, которое в итоге будет приложением под Android. Размер apk составил 2.3Mb. Когда я рассматривал кросс-платформенный фреймворк - ничего лучше по цене/возможностям не оказалось.

Comment: идеально, это конечно нативно для всех платформ, и с учетом специфики их UI. F xnj использовать, трудно сказать, популярный Ксамарин, так что думаю, с ним меньше проблем будет.

Comment: Я однозначно за Xamarin только по нему более менее приличные отзывы у разработчиков. Пара знакомых делали на Xamarin, еще пара знакомых использовали PhoneGap - плевались.

Comment: Однозначно могу посоветовать не использовать Xamarin, PhoneGap. Сложные приложения сделать на них без тормозов невозможно.

Comment: лучше писать несколько приложений.... кордова, ксамарин - кал

Answer (score 1):

Месяц работаю на Xamarin, пока все нравится. Если вы сторонник ООП, тогда лучшего и более охватывающего кросп. средства не найти. Сложные приложения пишутся без особых проблем, не говоря уже о простых. Компилятор работает шустро, я бы сказал не уступает оригинальной андроид студии. Очень удобна работать с отладкой и профилированием. Если же вы сторонник веб технологий то я бы смотрел в сторону кордовы.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, для разработки под iOS в Xamarin необходим мак. Видимо, других вариантов нет?

Comment: да или снять облако и компилить туда

Answer (score 1):

[Flutter](https://flutter.io/) — новый инструмент от Google, позволяющий разработчикам писать кроссплатформенные мобильные приложения, которые можно запускать как на Android, так и на iOS. Ещё один плюс Flutter — он ориентирован на [Material Design](https://material.io/) и предоставляет множество возможностей для работы с ним.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С чего начать?

- YouTube - [Introducing Flutter](https://youtu.be/fq4N0hgOWzU)
- Хабрахабр - [Введение и установка](https://habrahabr.ru/post/311412/)
- flutter.io - [Get Started](https://flutter.io/get-started/)

Answer (score 0):

[React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) — это фреймворк для разработки кроссплатформенных приложений для iOS и Android. История React Native довольно увлекательна: родившийся как внутренний проект Facebook в 2013-м, он вскоре стал одним из самых популярных фреймворков. Теперь же его код открыт и доступен на [Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native).
React Native очень дружелюбен к разработчикам с web бэкграундом и не требует изучения языков нативной разработки под iOS и Android – learn once, write anywhere*.

[image: разработка на react native]

С чего начать?

- Youtube - [Что такое React Native?](https://youtu.be/Q4BsAOhqPts)
- Хабрахабр - [Создаем приложение на JavaScript с помощью React Native](https://habrahabr.ru/company/plarium/blog/303328/)
- [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) Guide

* Выучи один раз, пиши под что угодно.